# Getting the value of clicked buttons and append them

Tags: android, xml, drag

I'm newbie in android development and going to create simple **drag'n'Drop** calculator.
My goal is to make buttons from **0 to 9** and create numbers by clicking them.

For example:

**0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9**

and by clicking them create number **245**, then drag this number, for example, into the **sum mark +**, then repeat second number and automatically retrieve results.

First, I'll show my code now...

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.coreprojects.calculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView calc_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    // This method comes from XML button = buttonClick
    public void buttonClick(View v) {

        // Textarea where numbers will be shown
        TextView TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calc_cache_1);

        // Get the ID of buttons
        Button calc_btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button calc_btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        // INT type numbers convert to string, because of [setText]
        String buttonText_1 = calc_btn_1.getText().toString();
        String buttonText_2 = calc_btn_2.getText().toString();

        // Result as text
        TV.setText(buttonText_1); // first number is not shown
        TV.setText(buttonText_2); // second number


        // alert
        /**
        String pressed = "Operation Done";
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("result").setMessage(pressed)
                .setNeutralButton("Done", null).show();
        */
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calc_cache_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/main_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="@string/button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="@string/button_2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Calculator</string>
    <string name="main_text"></string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="button_1">1</string>
    <string name="button_2">2</string>

</resources>
```

Now problem...

When i click on buttons, any time result shows number 2, because i think

> TV.setText(buttonText_2) is second command and first one is not read any more.

I tried to write together, like TV.setText(buttonText_1 + buttonText_2), but now it results **12**, even if i click any single button...

so how can I append numbers by clicking them? and also, if u see here, i have clickable button in XML, and get ID of pressed button, but i want it to be more dynamic.

For example: when i press button, don't get the ID of it, but simply identify the button ID and get value. i can show u simple analog in jQuery:

```
$(".button_class_not_ID").click(
    var elementValue = $(this).html();
    or
    var elementValue = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(elementValue);
);
```

Comment: i don't get that drag'n'drop thing in your context

Comment: no I don't need drag and drop solution, as i asked, i want to append numbers by clicking 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 buttons. I wrote this only for some info :)

Comment: setText replaces the content of the TV. calling it twice effectively voids the first call

Comment: right, i wrote this also and understood that, this is not good approach.

Comment: you hardcode the buttons that you consider. I don't see how you can make any operation this way